# ObjC files which only contain C (or minimal ObjC..)

Tags: objective-c, c

Every so often I'll start a little 'helper class' and find that I can cover my needs entirely with C functions (although these functions may often have ObjC within them, maybe return type or some args of NSDictionary* or whatever..),   and so i'll delete the @implementation and @interface and there is no class there at all, just .h and .m files..

What is the best practice, ought I change my .m file to a .c file? Or is this impossible/difficult with ObjectiveC types in there?  Is there any benefit to using a different file type that I'm unaware of or is what I'm doing just fine? (I only develop for OsX and iOS, and entirely with xCode, at least for now.)

thanks for your time :)

Comment: There's no requirement that an Objective-C source file (.m) include a class interface or implementation. If the code is using the Objective-C language, then it's an Objective-C source file and should be named with a .m extension.

Comment: Maybe you could consider using class methods instead of functions ?

Comment: thanks.  Do you understand from the question that I have considered this, it was a starting point?   I have several iOs apps which have been reviewed and passed and sold on the App Store which contain .m files with only C functions in them.  I know it works, the question is regarding implementation file types.  Thanks for your input I do appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a Command Line tool using Xcode it gives you a .m file for your code despite the fact that the initial file is not a class implementation file, so it may be best to follow this pattern (this is also true for the main file in other projects).

If you select a file in Xcode and have the right hand bar open you can let Xcode know how to parse that file. So if you've got ObjectiveC in your .c file you can change the Parse type from a C file to an ObjC file and it will all work correctly.

Comment: Thanks James.  It is indeed analogous to the main.m file, which is just a c function but which has an appDelegate object inside that function. great point

Comment: So i guess i'm doing just what Apple do, you get the points mate, thanks

Comment: An "object file" is a compiled source file, input to the linker, and uses a ".o" extension. You probably mean a class implementation file (with ".m" extension).